# What's the best way to highlight a telephone number in an Android App?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

[Question about android style]

I was wondering what is a good way to make clear that you can click on a telephone number and immediately call someone without copying & pasting the phone number. 
How can I persuade a user to click on a phone number ?

ps: my question is not about how to call someone when clicking on a phone number, but about how to style the phone number to show that it is clickable.

Comment: You may be interested in [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).  While I do not participate in that site (so take this advice with a grain of salt)  I think your question may be better asked there as it deals with the user experience.  You should review the [On-Topic guidelines](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in their help center first

Comment: Ok, I'm new to Stackoverflow, I will move my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe putting small phone icon beside number would be clear for user.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when the number is underlined like a HTML link, they understand right away.

```
TextView numberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_number);
numberText.setText("123-456-7890");
Linkify.addLinks(numberText, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

Comment: I want to try something different, but indeed: it's clear for users when you underline it like a HTML link.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the official documentation but there is no such standard defined for the same. So it is now upto you. 
Underlining the number is fine but does not go well with text blocks.
Using a different font color for the number will suit well. Using Blue is the trend;-)
But in the end it is about the design and color scheme of your app too. Seeing a number in different text color is enough a indicator that you can use it as a link